# What sort of bottom bracket does a Trek 1.5 2011 take?

Tags: bottom-bracket

My bottom bracket is on its way out.. No longer getting smooth rotation even without chain attached. I was wondering if anyone knew what sort of bottom bracket the frame supports? I've googled but the results are fairly mixed.

Also I assume I just need a special bottom bracket wrench to replace it, is that correct?

Cheers,
John

Comment: More importantly, what is the make and model of your crankset? That will determine both spindle type and length. Most bikes accept bottom brackets with a 68 mm shell and 1.37" x 24 tpi threading (with left-hand threads on the drive side.)

Comment: It's a FSA Vero, 50/34 (compact) apparently! Ideas? :)

Comment: I'm not a cycling expert..
I'm guessing the only real way to be sure of what I need is to literally remove the bottom bracket and see what size it is? I would have thought there'd be an easier way but Trek seem to not want to publicise what components are in my bike... does anyone have any solid evidence of what's in there? I've read a few conflicting things on the internet.. not sure really.

Comment: Poosible duplicate of http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14450/identifying-bottom-bracket

Comment: Before replacing it, try taking it apart, cleaning it thoroughly, greasing it back up and see if it works. Faster, cheaper and leaves you with that warm buzzy feeling of saving money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Trek directly. They informed me it's:

> 68x110mm square taper bottom bracket.

So there you have it! Hopefully this will help others googling such questions :)

Am I right in assuming this is the same as a JIS square taper?

Comment: 9 times out of 10, modern square tapers are JIS and not ISO.

Comment: I bought this: Shimano BB-UN55 Bottom Bracket British Thread  68-110mm and it worked a treat :)

Comment: In any case, if you switch a JIS and ISO with a modern cartridge BB, its not really a problem - a JIS crank on an ISO bb sits about a half centimeter further out than it would on an ISO bb, which isn't too much to totally mess up your chainline (of course, the right bb is preferable).

Comment: To add a bit to the first comment, Campagnolo square taper cranks use ISO. Miche, an Italian manufacturer, may have had ISO taper cranks at one point, but their more recent ones seem to have gone to JIS. I don't keep track of square taper cranksets much, but all the other ones I'm aware of should take JIS tapers.

Answer (score 7):

From [Trek's archives](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/2011/archive/15u) and [Bikepedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=2011&Brand=Trek&Model=1.5&Type=bike), it looks like that bike has an FSA Vero compact crankset (no mention of the bottom bracket (BB)).

From [the Amazon page for the FSA Vero Compact](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0083CP0A2) it appears the crank is compatible with a JIS square taper bottom bracket.

JIS square taper bottom bracket is a common type of cotterless bottom bracket, available from many manufacturers.

You'll need to check that the bottom bracket shell sizing and threading matches the BB, too.

You will need a special tool to get the crank off and another for the BB.

See also:

- [Sheldon Brown on Cotterless Crank removal](http://sheldonbrown.com/tooltips/cotterless.html)
- [John Allen on Cartridge BBs](http://sheldonbrown.com/tooltips/cartridge.html)
- [Park Tool on Cartridge BB servicing](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cartridge-bearing-type-bottom-bracket-service-bbt)
- [Park Tool on BB tool selection](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-tool-selection)
- [Park Tool on Cranks](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/categories/crank-service)

Comment: Also, it will need to be a 110 mm long spindle.